# How can I find a partial matched value in redis and update if it already exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

Currently, I am using sadd to insert address:number. Is there a way I can check if the address exists on a partial value match and then update/replace it with the new value?

```
    //Update payout
    var payoutUpdate = [];
    payoutUpdate.push(['sadd', coin + ':userPayout', [addr.split('.')[0], userPayout].join(':')]);

    redisClient.multi(payoutUpdate).exec(function(err, results){
        if (err){
            logger.error(logSystem, logComponent, 'Issue with custom payout!' + JSON.stringify(error));
            return;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SSCAN](https://redis.io/commands/sscan)

```
SSCAN key cursor [MATCH pattern] [COUNT count]
```